# ECMA- / Javascripts Array.prototype.forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecma262

Javascript (ECMAscript) supports the `Array.prototype.forEach` method since version 1.6 (ECMAscript edition 3, 2005). So quite a lot of browser already support that method and it's incredibly fast in comparison to jQuery's `$.each()` method for instance.
(Actually it beats all implementations, regardless which Javascript library)

In comparison to jQuery it's about 60-70% faster. Try it yourself on [forEach vs. jQuery](http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each) on JSPerf.

The only downside I have so far using it is, I can't figure a way to break the iteration early. Like `for`, `while` and `do-while` have a `break` statement, jQuerys `.each()` supports the `return false` to break the loop.

I looked into the *ECMAScript Edition 5 Specifications* (the latest I found), but they don't mention an early break from that loop.

So, question, would Mr. Douglas Crockford call this a `design error`?
Am I missing something and it is possible to break such a loop early?

**Edit**

Thanks for the answers so far. I guess since nobody came up with a "native" solution, there really is no implementation for that (maybe a feature?). Anyway, I don't really like the suggested methods so I fooled around a little and finally found one I do like (at least, better). Looks like:

```
var div     = document.createElement('div'),
divStyle    = div.style,
support     = jQuery.support,
arr         = ['MozTransform', 'WebkitTransform', 'OTransform'];

arr.slice(0).forEach(function(v,i,a){    
    if(divStyle[v] === ''){
       support.transform = v;
       a.length = 0;
    }
});
```

This is "real" production code. I looked for a nice way to lookup the css3 transform properties and I got lost in ecma5 specs & weird Javascript forums :-)

So, you may pass the array object itself as third parameter into the `.forEach` callback. I create a copy from the original array, calling `slice(0)` and set its `.length` property to 0 as soon as I found what I'm looking for. Works quite well.

If someone comes up with a better solution I'll edit this of course.

Comment: Time for a `goto break` anyone?

Comment: Well, if you could break early, it wouldn't really be `forEach`. It'd be `forSome`. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: funny, anyway I like the jQuery implementation for the feature that you **can** break an `.each()` loop early.

Comment: Yeah, that would seem handy. I wonder how the performance would compare on a large set where you simulate early termination by wrapping the code in an `if()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could use `every` instead. The function is designed to return `true` if the provided callback function returns `true` (truthy) for every element in the array, and `false` otherwise. Key point here is that once the callback function returns a falsly value, `every` immediatly returns `false` without iterating over the rest of the array. So just ignore the return value, and treat `every` as if it were `forEach`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].every(function(e) {
   alert(e);

   if (e > 2) return false; //break

   return true;
});
```

In this example, `alert` will only fire 3 times.

Of course the big cavet here is that you *must* return a truthy value if you want the loop to continue. In fact if you return nothing (undefined) the loop will stop. Alternativly, you could use `some` which behaves in the exact opposite manner; immediatly returns true when the callback function returns a truthy value and false if it never does.  In this case, `return true` would be your "break" statement. Backwards yes, but it saves you from having to `return true` simply to have the loop continue.

Now, if you are concerened with performance, I'd recomend just using a normal `for` loop, as there is significant overhead incurred when calling functionas that will add up very quickly with larger arrays. Using native functions helps somewhat, but the overhead of repeated calls to user-defined functions still exists and is non-trivial. At least this has been my experience, you should of course do your own testing.

Comment: nice. I wasn't aware of that method in ES5. Unfortunatly it looks like this is pretty rare implemented. Firefox doesn't support it. Good call anyway.

Comment: ok I have to take that back. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every. Anyway it's not working on my Firefox 3.6.11 (mac)

Comment: @jAndy: Weird. It works in Safari 4.1.1 and Firefox 3.6.10 on this old Mac.

Comment: @Chuck: It really is weird. I'll try it again on my Mac later, maybe there was another issue. Firefox 3.6.10 for Windows supports it also.

Comment: `every` and `some` has been supported in Firefox since version 1.5. Ancient history, basically. Something else is up. When you say "not working", do you mean the function does not exist, or it is behaving in an unexpected way?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you have a chunk of code that needs to be run against every single element. Don't use `forEach` to find an element or likewise "stop in the middle" operations. Apply this function to every element in an array.

You could (I think) use some sort of global indicator to check and return false if "found" or something.

```
var found = false;
array.forEach(function (k, v) { 
    if (found) 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if (v == 1) 
        { 
            found = true; 
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an error to break out of the iteration:

```
if (typeof BreakIteration == "undefined") {
  BreakIteration = new Error("BreakIteration");
}

try {
    [0,1,2,3,4].forEach(function(key, value) {            
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);

        if (value == 3) {
            throw BreakIteration;
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    if (error !== BreakIteration) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

This isn't exactly pretty.  I agree -- spec bug.

Comment: if that would be the only option I would not use it at all. That's not an option, I mean.. seriously..

Comment: I don't blame you.  It's horrible!

Comment: I guess I figured a "better" way. Still not convinient to me, but it comes close to it. Still would prefer a native way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use some other construct if I want to loop to search.

An option to break out of the forEach-ing is of course to `throw` something, though it's not really the way one would want to use throw...